# How to modify self and other classes with CSS :hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am coming from the .NET world and need an advice for a CSS styling:

We implemented a system which lets us design UI widgets with any SVG editor. For example a simpe play button would have a background rectangle and a triangle. In this widget all elements except the background have `pointer-events="none"`, so that the background receives all mouse events. But on hover over the background we want to style all foreground elements as well.

Suppose there are classes `.a` and `.b` and all elements are on the same level. To modify `.a` on hover you write:

```
.a:hover { stroke: red }
```

To modify `.b` when hovered over `.a` you write:

```
.a:hover ~ .b { stroke: red }
```

But how can i do both at once? Of course one can write both statements, but what when there is another class `.c`? Would it need its own statement as well or is there something like:

```
//fantasy code
.a:hover ~ (.a + .b + .c) { stroke: red }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is that possible to change multiple elements appearance on hover without Javascript, based on class name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714810/is-that-possible-to-change-multiple-elements-appearance-on-hover-without-javascr)

Comment: It's similar, but i would not call it a duplicate as all my elements are on the same level. I will add a little more context.

Comment: It's the exact same fix, it doesn't matter if they're on different levels or not

Comment: The accepted answer from the other question only works if the elements are on the same level. It does not work for the question of the OP: "I have a structure of divs inside divs, something like:". People search for the question, not the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to post [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/whats-the-best-way-of-centering-a-div-vertically-with-css?rq=1) instead. My bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They all need their own selectors, but you can separate them with `,`:

```
.a:hover, .a:hover ~ .b, .a:hover ~ .c { stroke: red; }
```

(Note that `~` is “sibling after” and not “at the same time as”.)

If they have anything else in common (say they’re all `<div>`s or you can give them each another class), use that:

```
.a:hover, .a:hover ~ div { stroke: red; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the info on ~. Is there another symbol to select all elements in the same level? not only siblings after, but also the ones before?

Comment: @thalm: No, there’s not — one of the primary complaints with CSS selectors. You’ll probably need JavaScript. (Although some context might be helpful, too.)

Comment: @thalm: Hmm… why is the background on the same level as the rest of the elements? Shouldn’t it contain them, or at least be the first element anyways?

Comment: In a simple SVG document its quite common to have all elements on the same level because you can only build hierarchies with <g> elements. But its right, we just have to take care that the background is the first one, which also makes sense visually as the background should be drawn first. Thanks for the answer, it works!

Answer (score 1):

You could probably accomplish this with SASS loops, but if there's only three classes I'd just go:

```
.a:hover, 
.a:hover ~ .b, 
.a:hover ~ .c {
    color: red;
}
```